# find out ProgID for com object using pywin32

Tags: python, winapi, com, pywin32

I can declare a com object in python via pywin32 using the following code

```
import win32com.client
Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

But how do I find out the ProgID (ie "Outlook.Application") for other com objects if I don't know them beforehand?

Comment: Unclear what your question is... You can discover by looking in the registry, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and find a bunch of ProgIDs. The OLEVIEW.EXE tool that ships with Visual Studio shows objects and type libraries that are available.  But, usually I don't create objects at random but have an idea of the object I want to create and I try to create that one. What difference does it make if there are other objects? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/-progid--key

Comment: thanks got it I can find out the progid using regedit

Comment: hi, it seems you have solved the issue, therefore you can post an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0):

It was suggested I post my comment as an answer:

Unclear what your question is... You can discover by looking in the registry, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and find a bunch of ProgIDs. The OLEVIEW.EXE tool that ships with Visual Studio shows objects and type libraries that are available. But, usually I don't create objects at random but have an idea of the object I want to create and I try to create that one. What difference does it make if there are other objects?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/-progid--key